# Search and aggregation on two indices

Tags: elasticsearch

Two indexes are created with the dates.

First index mapping:

```
PUT /index_one
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "date_start": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second index mapping:

```
PUT /index_two
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "date_end": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Need to find a date in a certain range and perform aggregation average of the dates difference.

Tried to make a request like this:

```
GET /index_one,index_two/_search?scroll=1m&q=[2021-01-01+TO+2021-12-31]&filter_path=aggregations,hits.total.value,hits.hits
{
    "aggs": {
        "filtered_dates": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "date_start"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "date_end"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "avg_date": {
                    "avg": {
                        "script": {
                            "lang": "painless",
                            "source": "doc['date_end'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli() - doc['date_begin'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli()"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following response to the request:

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 16508
        },
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "index_one",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "93a34c5b-101b-45ea-9965-96a2e0446a28",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "date_begin": "2021-02-26 07:26:29.732+0300"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "filtered_dates": {
            "meta": {},
            "doc_count": 0,
            "avg_date": {
                "value": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me if it is possible to make a query with search and aggregation over two indices in Elasticsearch? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you stored `date_start` on the document which contains `date_end`, it'd be **much** easier to figure out the average — check my answer to [Store time related data in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202816/store-time-related-data-in-elasticsearch/66216411#66216411).

---

Now, the script context operates on **one** single document at a time and has "no clue" about the other, potentially related docs. So if you don't store both dates at the same time in *at least* one doc, you'd need to *somehow* connect the docs nonetheless.

One option would be to use their `id`s:

```json
POST index_one/_doc
{ "id":1, "date_start": "2021-01-01" }

POST index_two/_doc
{ "id":1, "date_end": "2021-12-31" }

POST index_one/_doc/2
{ "id":2, "date_start": "2021-01-01" }

POST index_two/_doc/2
{ "id":2, "date_end": "2021-01-31" }
```

After that, it's possible to:

1. Target multiple indices — as you already do.
2. Group the docs by their IDs and select only those that include at least 2 buckets (assuming two buckets represent the start & the end).
3. Obtain the [`min`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html) & [`max`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) dates — essentially cherry-picking the `date_start` and `date_end` to be used later down the line.
4. Use a [`bucket_script` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) to calculate their difference (in milliseconds).
5. Leverage a top-level [average bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-avg-bucket-aggregation.html) to run over all the difference buckets and ... average them.

In concrete terms:

```json
GET /index_one,index_two/_search?scroll=1m&q=[2021-01-01+TO+2021-12-31]&filter_path=aggregations,hits.total.value,hits.hits
{
  "aggs": {
    "grouped_by_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "min_doc_count": 2,
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_date": {
          "min": {
            "field": "date_start"
          }
        },
        "max_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date_end"
          }
        },
        "diff": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "min": "min_date",
              "max": "max_date"
            },
            "script": "params.max - params.min"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg_duration_across_the_board": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "grouped_by_id>diff",
        "gap_policy": "skip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If everything goes right, you'll end up with:

```json
...
"aggregations" : {
  "grouped_by_id" : {
    ...
  },
  "avg_duration_across_the_board" : {
    "value" : 1.70208E10        <-- 17,020,800,000 milliseconds ~ 4,728 hrs
  }
}
```

⚠️ *Caveat: note that the 2nd level `terms` aggregation has an adjustable `size`. You'll probably need to increase it to cover more docs. But there are theoretical and practical limits as to how far it makes sense to increase it.*

---

Shameless plug: this was inspired in part by the chapter [*Aggregations & Buckets*](https://elasticsearchbook.com/learn-elasticsearch/7-aggregations-buckets-ad9d0fcc85e6479a991ec6f67548b6bd) in my recently published [Elasticsearch Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/) — containing lots of other real-world, non-trivial examples

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This ID appears in two indexes, but has a different name. Is it possible in this case to group documents?

Comment: Yes — use whatever Id field you got and let me know how it went.

Comment: Clarification - the two indexes have different field names. For instance, "uuid", "guid"

Comment: Oh I see — terms agg supports a script too so you can target either of those.

Comment: In my example, it does not work, because the field is not integer, but text. An error occurs: "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [gid] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."

Comment: Add a keyword multifield like here -- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param

Comment: If I understand correctly, then the index should be re-created. Is it possible to do something if there are already documents in the index?

Comment: Yes. I think the following should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817243/convert-timestamps-to-datetime-for-use-in-elasticsearch-aggregations/66818877#66818877 You can adapt it to your text field.

Comment: I was able to update the fields in the index. But the average turned out to be very large - 6357086.4. The average should be ~10,000 milliseconds.

Comment: Can you test it with a very small subset of documents so that the avg can be manually compared?