# Convert timestamps to datetime for use in Elasticsearch aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-date

I have an index of SendGrid event data:

```
"_source": {
    "externalId": "9283cc1d-b003-xxxx-a5af-84fcf31c4181",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1616515214,
    "event": "processed",
    "uid": null,
    "id": null,
    "sendgridEventId": null,
    "smtpId": null,
    "sgMessageId": null,
    "sgEventId": null,
    "sendgridEvent": null,
    "type": null,
    "category": [],
    "reason": null,
    "status": null,
    "url": null,
    "useragent": null,
    "ip": null,
    "response": null,
    "tls": null,
    "attempt": null,
    "sendAt": null,
    "asmGroupId": null
}
```

Now I like to aggregate all of these events for a given day using the `timestamp` attribute.

```
GET /sendgridevententity/_search
{
  "query":
   {
    "match_all": {}
   },
   "aggs": {
     "amount_per_day": {
       "date_histogram": {
         "field": "timestamp",
         "calendar_interval": "1d"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, this just yields all the single events as they all have a different timestamp and the aggregation does not group them by day.

How can I convert the timestamps to `date` and then run the aggregation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of a [multi field mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html). Here's how it works.

1. Update the existing mapping with a new date "sub-field". I'm assuming `timestamp` was originally mapped as a `long`. I'm also assuming the timestamps are in epoch seconds, thereby the explicitly set [`format`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats):

```json
POST sendgridevententity/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "timestamp": {
      "type": "long",
      "fields": {
        "as_date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_second"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. This new property now needs to be picked up and your data needs to be **reindexed**. You can trigger a reindex call via a [cool little trick](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#picking-up-a-new-property) — sending an empty `_update_by_query` request:

```json
POST sendgridevententity/_update_by_query
```

3. After the reindex operation finishes, you can target the new date field through the dot notation:

```json
GET /sendgridevententity/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "amount_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp.as_date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd", 
        "calendar_interval": "1d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

⚠️ Depending your index size and many other factors, the `_update_by_query` request **may appear** to time out. It's possible to set [`wait_for_completion=false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-task-api) which'll trigger an asynchronous background task instead.

Note that I used `size: 0` in the final request. It's a handy tool for returning [only the aggregation results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#return-only-agg-results).

Comment: One additional question: I like to use it in a Kibana Visualization. But for the Bucket I can not use the format and it just states that there is no field of type "date". Is there a way to use this field there as well?

Comment: Yes, it should be. It may be necessary to recreate the [Index Pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html) though so that it picks up the date field too. BTW it's not `date` -- it's `timestamp.as_date` and that's what should be able to choose from the dropdown when the index pattern is up to date.